# How to replace every second space with a comma the Pythonic way

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, iteration, data-manipulation

I have a string with first and last names all separated with a space. 
For example:

```
installers = "Joe Bloggs John Murphy Peter Smith"
```

I now need to replace every second space with ', ' (comma followed by a space) and output this as string.

The desired output is

```
print installers 
Joe Bloggs, John Murphy, Peter Smith
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to split the string into a space-separated list of names, get an iterator for the list, then loop over the iterator in a for loop, collecting the first name and then advancing to loop iterator to get the second name too.

```
names = installers.split()
it = iter(names)
out = []
for name in it:
    next_name = next(it)
    full_name = '{} {}'.format(name, next_name)
    out.append(full_name)
fixed = ', '.join(out)
print fixed

'Joe Bloggs, John Murphy, Peter Smith'
```

The one line version of this would be

```
>>> ', '.join(' '.join(s) for s in zip(*[iter(installers.split())]*2))
'Joe Bloggs, John Murphy, Peter Smith'
```

this works by creating a list that contains the *same iterator* twice, so the zip function returns both parts of the name.  See also the grouper recipe from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should be a able to do this with a regex that that finds the spaces and replaces the last one:

```
import re
installers = "Joe Bloggs John Murphy Peter Smith"
re.sub(r'(\s\S*?)\s', r'\1, ',installers)
# 'Joe Bloggs, John Murphy, Peter Smith'
```

This says, find a space followed by some non-spaces followed by a space and replace it with the found space followed by some non-spaces and ", ". You could add `installers.strip()` if there's a possibility of trailing spaces on the string.

Comment: This works also. I had fought with Regex while trying to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Had a similar problem. Neat solution with regex